# Remove the duplicate id based on status without pandas?

Tags: python, jmespath

I need to write a output from aws account to excel sheet. I am using graphql and using jmespath.search to map the expressions and store in a excel sheet. I am facing issue with duplicate Id getting stored. I am using filter to merge two columns values into single columns values such as "active" or ""inactive". While storing the data I am getting duplicate Ids as well. I need to remove the duplicate id based on "inactive" status and add active Ids alone into a sheet.

For example let us take that response is coming in list format as below.

```
data = [
    {"id": 1, "deregistered ": True, "deactivated":True, "location": true},
    {"id": 1, "deregistered ": False, "deactivated": False, "location": true},
    {"id": 2, "deregistered ": False, "deactivated":False, "location": true},
]
```

Now, I need to write this into excel sheet by removing the duplicate id based on status. I need only below values from the data. i.e remove the id 1 if it is duplicate and store only active ids.

```
output={'id':1, 'status' : 'active', 'location': true},{'id':2, 'status' : 'inactive', 'location': true}
```

How to achieve this using python but without pandas. and I am using jmespath.search and mapping the values.

I tried as below but not getting the logic.

```
for val in data:
    loc_enabled = val.get("location")
    if loc_enabled:
        search = """
               {
               "id": id, 
               "status": ((deregistered == `true` || deactivated == `true`) && `Inactive`) ||                 `Active`,
                "location":location
                 }"""
    test = jmespath.search(search, val)

    if test:
        loc_enabled.append(test)

    print(loc_enabled)
```

I need to know where to handle the logic here **without pandas.** and get the desired results
`

Comment: Does [this](https://pastebin.com/gk2Qdb6P) work for you?

Comment: `from functools import reduce`. Then `sorted(reduce(lambda acc, it: ({**acc, **{it['id']: it}} if (it["id"] not in acc.keys()) or (acc[it["id"]]['status'] == 'inactive' and it['id'] == 'active') else acc), data, {}).values(), key=lambda x: x['id'])`

Comment: What does _without pandas_ mean to you? Grouping in not something JMESPath is good at, so I am not totally sure this would be something you can achieve with it.

Comment: if (it["id"] not in acc.keys()) or (acc[it["id"]]['status'] == 'inactive' and it['id'] == 'active')
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys' @Wakeme UpNow

Comment: Change to `print(sorted(reduce(lambda acc, it: ({**acc, **{it['id']: it}} if (it["id"] not in acc.keys()) or (acc[it["id"]]['status'] == 'inactive' and it['id'] == 'active') else acc), data, dict()).values(), key=lambda x: x['id']))` then (Change `{}` to `dict()`)

Comment: cool ! It worked. Thanks a lot !
print(sorted(reduce(lambda acc, it: ({**acc, **{it['id']: it}} if (it["id"] not in acc.keys()) or (acc[it["id"]]['status'] == 'inactive' and it['id'] == 'active') else acc), data, dict()).values(), key=lambda x: x['id'])) this worked, but not getting your point then (Change {} to dict ?

Comment: I use python 3.9, but in older version `{}` create a new `set` instead of `dict`. So I have to switch out to named object initialization

Comment: @WakemeUpNow, Small clarification only, is it possible to add this code in my way using jmespath? can you please help me in adding your code to jmespath.search way. I have edited the data now pls check?

Comment: The simplest method is to breakdown into `2` steps. First, extract data using JMESPath to list of data. Then apply the above code to deduplicate entry

Comment: But if you insists, try query twice (map entry to id). First query only `active` status, and then `inactive`. Then merge `active` (right) onto `inactive` (left)

Comment: @WakemeUpNow, Is it possible to put your code as an answer so it will be helpful for me to learn the code. the way you said to query twice using lambda methods.

Comment: @WakemeUpNow, Please let me know could you help me on this part?

Comment: I can;t do it with jmespath, but I can do it with jq `jq.compile('((. | map({(.id | tostring): select(.status == "inactive")}) | add) + (. | map({(.id | tostring): select(.status == "active")}) | add)) | to_entries[] | .value').input(data).all()`